# In tensorflow, when calling tf.memory(), what does unreliable: true mean?

Tags: tensorflow, memory, tensorflow.js

My call to `tf.memory()` results in:

```
{
  unreliable: true,
  numTensors: 125289,
  numDataBuffers: 125289,
  numBytes: 12289704
}
```

It does not provide a reason for being unreliable, as the documentation suggests, and I cannot find information about what it means.

What does it mean for the memory to be unreliable in tensorflow?

Comment: Flag `unreliable` in the result means that the calculation is not reliable. For example, the presented results could be higher than the actual memory usage due to automatic garbage collection.

Comment: No reasons in the result seem suspicious, @zain-syed what version are you using?

Comment: @user1635327 reason is only given when backend is set to `cpu`. i know, it doesn't make much sense, but that's from the code. otherwise `reasons` property is never set.

Comment: The backend is cpu, and the version is @tensorflow/tfjs 3.8.0 and @tensorflow/tfjs-node 3.9.0

Comment: it should have a `reason` field. but like it was said earlier currently only reason is that printed values are high watermark and can be lower due to garbage collection - currently there is no other `reason` implemented. so entire `unreliable` property is pretty much meaningless right now.